# prove using natural deduction truth functional logic

Tags: logic

can someone help me with my practice problems pls 
prove using natural deduction truth functional logic 
A → (B → C), D → B ∴ A → (D → C)

1   A → (B → C)
2   D → B
3       A
4           D
5           B
6           B → C   →I 5
7       C

Comment: Rather, we can help, but first you should try then show us as much as you can do on your own.  [That will also tell us *which* proof system you are working with.]

Comment: 1 A → (B → C)  
2 D → B  
3  A  
4   D  
5   B  
6   B → C →I 5 
7  C  
@GrahamKemp

Comment: im not forsure if its correct or not I put it in the natural deduction proof solver and it kept saying error

Answer (score 0):

The steps you have, so far, are correct.  The justifications are as follows

```
 1. |  A → (B → C)    Premise
 2. |_ D → B          Premise
 3. |  |_ A           Assumption
 4. |  |  |_ D        Assumption
 5. |  |  |  B        →E 2,4      Conditional Elimination
 6. |  |  |  B → C    →E 1,3
 7. |  |  |  C        →E 6,5
```

Now of course, you need to discharge those assumptions with conditional introduction.

```
 8. |  |  D → C       →I 4-7      Conditional Introduction
 9. |  A → (D → C)    →I 3-8
```

**Remark:** When presenting a proof, it is helpful to indicate when an assumption is raised and discharged, usually with some form of indentation or boxing.  The presentation above is called Fitch Style.